# BigInteger.ToString() returns more than 50 decimal digits

Tags: .net-4.0, tostring, biginteger

I'm using .NET 4 [System.Numerics.BigInteger Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268287%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and I'm getting results different from the documentation.

In the documentation of [BigInteger.ToString() Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268341%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) It says:

> The ToString() method supports 50
>   decimal digits of precision. That is,
>   if the BigInteger value has more than
>   50 digits, only the 50 most
>   significant digits are preserved in
>   the output string; all other digits
>   are replaced with zeros.

I have some code that takes a 60 decimal digits `BigInteger` and converts it to a `string`. The 60 significant decimal digits `string` didn't lose any significant digits:

```
const string vString = "123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890";
Assert.AreEqual(60, vString.Length);
BigInteger v = BigInteger.Parse(vString);
Assert.AreEqual(60, v.ToString().Length);
Assert.AreEqual('9', v.ToString()[58]);
Assert.AreEqual('1', v.ToString()[0]);
Assert.AreEqual(vString, v.ToString());
Assert.AreEqual(vString, v.ToString("G"));
```

All the asserts pass.

What exactly does the quoted part of the documentation mean?

Comment: Got to be a bug in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation is a little unclear here, this limit only applies when **formatting** the string, for example:

```
v.ToString("0"); "123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678900000000000"
v.ToString("n0"); "123,456,789,012,345,678,901,234,567,890,123,456,789,012,345,678,900,000,000,000"
```

[The exception is formatting it as `"R"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268260(v=VS.100).aspx), which gives the original round-tripped value:

```
v.ToString("R"); "123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567891"
```

Comment: formatting using "G" { v.ToString("G") } gives the same 60 significant digits output. What are the formats that you only get 50 digits for?

Comment: @brickner: I believe only `g` and `r` will return the full original value for any length, but I'm not 100% sure, rarely use numbers this large in our projects.

Comment: The strings above cannot be reproduced on my machine (.NET 4.5.2). Was the above output generated with the official final release (RTM) of .NET 4.0? It is hard to believe they changed this functionality. It seems kind of breaking. Maybe you made the above output with a beta version of .NET 4.0 (even if the final version was released)? Can anyone document when this functionality was changed?