# In .NET, does the string returned by BigInteger.ToString() reflect the full precision of BigInteger?

Tags: c#, .net, biginteger

Until today I (implicitly) assumed that when I output a `BigInteger` via the parameterless (overridden) instance method `BigInteger.ToString()` then the return string would contain the complete and exact decimal representation of my "big" integer.

But on [the MSDN doc page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268260.aspx) I read:

> "In most cases, the **ToString** method supports 50 decimal digits of precision. That is, if the **BigInteger** value has more than 50 digits, only the 50 most significant digits are preserved in the output string; all other digits are replaced with zeros. However, **BigInteger** supports the **"R"** standard format specifier, which is intended to round-trip numeric values. The string returned by the **ToString(String)** method with the **"R"** format string preserves the whole **BigInteger** value and can then be parsed with the **Parse** or **TryParse** method to restore its original value without any loss of data"._

However, I have not been able to find an example where `myBigInt.ToString()` differs from `myBigInt.ToString("R")`. The Remarks example from the above page does not, as claimed, provide an example, in my version of the framework (.NET 4.0 SP1). (Also `"G"` and `"R"` seem to be equivalent for `BigInteger`.)

**Is it safe to assume that the paramterless `ToString()` gives the full decimal expansion of the integer?** Did they change framework behavior, or has the above mentioned example code always been wrong?

**Note:** SO shows me [this "similar question" 2984184](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984184/) after I wrote this one, but I'm still submitting my question because the answer of 2984184 does not really claryfy how the zero-parameter `ToString()` works.

**EDIT BY MYSELF:**

It was a bit incosequent of me to link the `ToString(String)` overload on MSDN when my question is (primarily) about the `ToString()` overload. So see also [MSDN on `BigInteger.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268341) which mentions the 50 digits limit as well but does not provide an example with more than 50 digits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Decompiling the .NET 4.0 framework gives this chain of calls:

```
BigInteger.ToString
BigNumber.FormatBigInteger( ... format:= null ...)
BigNumber.ParseFormatSpecifier(format ...)
```

within which we have

```
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(format))
    return 'R';
```

so it can be seen that **in this implementation**, `ToString()` is equivalent to `ToString("R")`. But, [as pointed out by @PaulPhillips](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11345910), given that the docs (slightly confusedly) explicitly disclaim the reliability of this, I would say the safest (and in any case the most self-documenting) thing to do is **use "R" when you need full fidelity**.

Comment: "so it can be seen that in this implementation, ToString() is equivalent to ToString("R")" -- Worth mentioning: that does not disprove the promise by the docs that ToString() is equivalent to ToString("G"): that's still true if ToString("G") and ToString("R") have the same effect.

Comment: .net 3.5 has its own implementation of ToString. So this may be new to .net 4.0. In fact, there is not even a BigNumber class in 3.5.

Comment: Nevermind - BigNumber is not public in 3.5 (it's internal). I wonder if its a documentation bleed from this earlier internal implementation.

Comment: @hatchet I think `BigNumber` is just an internal helper class. I think I see what the documentation is trying to say; it's just not quite as crystal clear as it might be.

Comment: On the possibility that future framework versions might change the behavior of `ToString()`: Who would want the "default" visualization of an arbitrary-precision type to have a bunch of digits **"replaced with zeroes"** (as the doc says)? It's like saying "This type has arbitrary precision internally, but we present it to the users as a fixed-precision (50-digits) number". Silly, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think it is a safe assumption.

Since they have explicitly documented it as *not* doing that, it seems like a bad idea to rely on this behavior. If it actually *is* the same, then its undocumented and could theoretically change at any time (though this seems unlikely).

Comment: In any case, the documentation is wrong (wrt. the current implementation), and the example in the "Remarks" section on the page on the `ToString(String)` overload does **not** produce the output they claim: The `"G"` format loses no information (in their own example).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code the `ToString()` method simply calls:

`BigNumber.FormatBigInteger(this, (string)null, NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo);`

From there, the internal `BigNumber.FormatBigInteger(BigInteger value, string format, NumberFormatInfo info)` method has the following logic:

```
int digits = 0;
char format1 = BigNumber.ParseFormatSpecifier(format, out digits);
```

So, now we look at the `BigNumber.ParseFormatSpecifier(string format, out int digits)` method and discover that because it passed in a null string it simply returns the character **'R'** with the number of digits (`digits`) equal to -1. Whereas, if you actually passed in a string format you can specify the number of digits as well, for example... 'R25' and it will parse out 25 as the number of digits.

This is what I understood by looking at the source code.

Comment: It looks like `"R25"` pads with zeros **before** the number if the number has less than 25 figures in the first place. When the number has, say, 1000 digits, it looks like `"R"` and `"R25"` produce the same output, and no zeros are added, and no digits are replaced with zeros in that case.